# How to print value NegativeImbalance when withdraw some free balance (balance pallet)

Tags: substrate, polkadot

In my code I have:

```
let withdraw_balance = <pallet_balances::Module<T> as Currency<_>>::withdraw(&participant,workshop.fee,WithdrawReasons::RESERVE,ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive);
```

And I debug like that

```
frame_support::debug::native::debug!("withdraw_balance:{:#?}",withdraw_balance);
```

It is error because this trait not implement std::fmt::Debug for NegativeImbalance.
I try to implement Debug for NegativeImbalance, but I fail (I am newbie). Although, When i read doc in Substrate, they give some hint to implement Debug for struct NegativeImbalance (https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v3.0.0-monthly-2021-05/pallet_balances/struct.NegativeImbalance.html)like this:
[implement Trait Debug for struct NegativeImbalance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyhTf.png)

Thank you!!!

I extract some code like that: (I follow 1 blog and full code is here:https://arveknudsen.com/posts/substrate-runtime-module/)

```
#[weight=10_000]
fn participate(origin) -> dispatch::DispatchResult{
    let participant = ensure_signed(origin)?;

    frame_support::debug::native::debug!("sender:{}",participant);
   
    let workshop = match <Workshop<T>>::get() {
        Some(workshop) => {
            Ok(workshop)
        }
        None => {
            Err("no workshop announced")
        }
    }?;

    let mut members = <Members<T>>::get();

    match members.binary_search(&participant){

        Ok(_) => Err(Error::<T>::AlreadyParticipant.into()),
        Err(index) => {
            members.insert(index,participant.clone());
            Members::<T>::put(members);
            Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::AddParticipants(participant.clone()));

            let mut num_participants = <NumParticipants>::get();
            frame_support::debug::native::debug!("num_participants:{}",num_participants);

            for i in 0..num_participants {
                let acc_id = <Participants<T>>::get(i);
                if acc_id == participant.clone() {
                    return Ok(());
                }
            }
            let withdraw_balance = <pallet_balances::Module<T> as Currency<_>>::withdraw(&participant,workshop.fee,WithdrawReasons::RESERVE,ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive)?;
            frame_support::debug::native::debug!("withdraw_balance:{:#?}",withdraw_balance);
            frame_support::debug::native::debug!("total_issuancei_after_withdraw:{:?}",<pallet_balances::Module<T> as Currency<_>>::total_issuance());
            frame_support::debug::native::debug!("total_balance_after_withdraw:{:?}",<pallet_balances::Module<T> as Currency<_>>::total_balance(&participant));
            <Participants<T>>::insert(num_participants,&participant);
            num_participants = num_participants.saturating_add(1);
            frame_support::debug::native::debug!("num_participants_after_insert:{}",num_participants);
            <NumParticipants>::put(num_participants);

            let mut budget = <Budget<T>>::get();
            //budget = budget.into() + workshop.unwrap().fee;
            let mut budget_u32 = TryInto::<u32>::try_into(budget).ok().unwrap();
            //let fee_u32 = TryInto::<u32>::try_into(workshop.as_ref().unwrap().fee).ok().unwrap();
            let fee_u32 = TryInto::<u32>::try_into(workshop.fee).ok().unwrap();
            budget_u32 = budget_u32.saturating_add(fee_u32);

            frame_support::debug::native::debug!("budget_u32:{}",budget_u32);
            budget = budget_u32.into();

            <Budget<T>>::put(budget);

            Ok(())

        }


    }

}
```

And I have bug like this:
[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmyeI.png)

PURPOSE: I want to understand deeply about Balance Pallet and check some terminology like Imbalance / NegativeImbalance/ PositiveImbalance/ Total Issuance,...

Comment: Can you please post the exact code and the error message.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi i already updated my question. Thanks you for helping me.